# Ansible run command with an updated PATH

Tags: variables, environment, ansible

I'm doing the following:

```
  tasks:
- name: Output env vars
  shell: echo $PATH $ANDROID_HOME > path.txt
  environment:
    ANDROID_HOME: "/home/{{ deploy_user }}/android-sdk-linux"
    PATH: "{{ ansible_env.ANDROID_HOME }} /tools:/platform-tools:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
```

The output on the server is:

```
$ less path.txt
 {{ ansible_env.ANDROID_HOME }}/tools:/platform-tools:{{ ansible_env.PATH }} /home/azureuser/android-sdk-linux}}
```

It seems that the string is not interpolated.

Exactly the same playbook with the task:

```
  tasks:
- name: Output $PATH
  shell: echo $PATH $ANDROID_HOME > path.txt
  environment:
    ANDROID_HOME: "/home/{{ deploy_user }}/android-sdk-linux"
    PATH: "/tools:/platform-tools:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
```

gives

```
$ less path.txt
  /tools:/platform-tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games /home/azureuser/android-sdk-linux
```

which is what I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use an undefined variable, in your case

> PATH: "{{ ansible_env.ANDROID_HOME }} /tools:/platform-tools:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"

I suppose you don't have "ANDROID_HOME" variable on the remote node so all the line is not interpreted.

You need to replace "{{ ansible_env.ANDROID_HOME }}" by "{{ ANDROID_HOME }}" or use another logic.

Comment: That's what I've in the end: setting up a `android_path` in the general `vars.yml` then referenced it in the two others: `ANDROID_HOME: "{{ android_home_path }}"` and `PATH: "{{ android_home_path }}/tools:{{ android_home_path }}/platform-tools:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"`.

Thanks!